# What is the volume enclosed by a plane $y = 23$ and a torus of radius $27$ and inner radius $4$

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

I want to find the volume on the right of the plane (the smaller volume).

I think that the torus can be thought of as a volume of revolution of a circle about the z-axis, and that the bounds for integration can be set as y = 23 and y = 27 + 4 or 31. I'm not sure if that would work though.

The parameters of the torus are:

$x = (27+4\cos v)\cos u$

$y = (27+4\cos v)\sin u$

$z = 4\sin v$

And $4$ is the radius of the tube.

Thank you
[image]

Comment: Is the inner radius $4$ or $14$?

Comment: The inner radius is 4, and by inner radius, I mean the radius of the cylinder, if the torus was stretched out.

Comment: Step 1:  Parametrize the torus.  Then things should take care of themselves.

Comment: I added  the parameters to the torus in the question as requested.

Comment: For parameter values $u=v=0,$ you get $x = 31,$ $y=0,$ $z = 0.$ Now find the points closest to the origin; these all lie on a circle in the $z=0$ plane. None of this matches your figure. Even if we change $27$ to $25$ it doesn't match. So the first thing is to make very, very sure you know what problem you're trying to solve and construct an appropriate figure for it.

Comment: I have changed the image to match the parameters, and the plane intersecting the torus is y = 23.

Comment: I think that the torus can be thought of as a volume of revolution of a circle about the z-axis, and that the bounds for integration can be set as y = 23 and y = 27 + 4 or 31. I'm not sure if that would work though.